# How do I iterate over two consecutive indexed objects using purrr::map()?

Tags: r, iteration, tidyverse, purrr

I have >100 csv-files, all with the same structure. Each csv-file is a daily snapshot of the metadata of all documents in a system. The filenames contain the snapshot-date. The metadata contain Document_ID, Status, Author and some other columns. Every row represents a document’s metadata.

I would like to create a log of all changes over time. So I first load all the files into a single tibble, using:

```
df <- fs::dir_ls(path = "Files") %>% 
  purrr::map_dfr(read_csv, .id = "Filename")
```

The original filename containing the snapshot-date is now in the first column. Here’s a simplified reprex of the resulting df:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Filename = c(rep("File_2020-09-27", 2), rep("File_2020-09-28", 3), rep("File_2020-09-29", 4), rep("File_2020-09-30", 5)),
             Doc_ID = c(seq(1, 2), seq(1, 3), seq(1, 4), seq(1, 5)),
             Status = c("Finished", "Started", 
                        "Finished", "Started", "Started", 
                        "Finished", "Started", "Finished", "Started",
                        "Finished", "Waiting", "Finished", "Started", "Started"),
             Author = c("John", "John",
                        "John", "Mike", "John",
                        "John", "Mike", "John", "Mike",
                        "John", "Mike", "John", "Mike", "Betty"),
             Other_column = rnorm(14))
df
#> # A tibble: 14 x 5
#>    Filename        Doc_ID Status   Author Other_column
#>    <chr>            <int> <chr>    <chr>         <dbl>
#>  1 File_2020-09-27      1 Finished John          0.319
#>  2 File_2020-09-27      2 Started  John          0.633
#>  3 File_2020-09-28      1 Finished John          2.27 
#>  4 File_2020-09-28      2 Started  Mike          0.302
#>  5 File_2020-09-28      3 Started  John          0.905
#>  6 File_2020-09-29      1 Finished John          0.451
#>  7 File_2020-09-29      2 Started  Mike          1.46 
#>  8 File_2020-09-29      3 Finished John          0.306
#>  9 File_2020-09-29      4 Started  Mike         -0.850
#> 10 File_2020-09-30      1 Finished John         -2.03 
#> 11 File_2020-09-30      2 Waiting  Mike          0.250
#> 12 File_2020-09-30      3 Finished John          0.637
#> 13 File_2020-09-30      4 Started  Mike         -0.207
#> 14 File_2020-09-30      5 Started  Betty        -2.13
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that documents never disappear, they just change their status or author. To manually create the desired output, I first create separate tibbles for every daily snapshot:

```
Docs_1 <- df %>% filter(Filename == "File_2020-09-27")
Docs_2 <- df %>% filter(Filename == "File_2020-09-28")
Docs_3 <- df %>% filter(Filename == "File_2020-09-29")
Docs_4 <- df %>% filter(Filename == "File_2020-09-30")
```

For every consecutive pair of daily snapshots I then identify the rows of the next day, that are new or different from the previous day. I'm only interested in these. "New" or "different" relates to the combination of `Doc_ID`, `Status` and `Author`:

```
Changes_1_2 <- Docs_2 %>% dplyr::anti_join(Docs_1, by = c("Doc_ID", "Status", "Author"))
```

resulting in:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Filename        Doc_ID Status  Author Other_column
  <chr>            <int> <chr>   <chr>         <dbl>
1 File_2020-09-28      2 Started Mike          0.807
2 File_2020-09-28      3 Started John          0.336
```

```
Changes_2_3 <- Docs_3 %>% dplyr::anti_join(Docs_2, by = c("Doc_ID", "Status", "Author"))
```

resulting in:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Filename        Doc_ID Status   Author Other_column
  <chr>            <int> <chr>    <chr>         <dbl>
1 File_2020-09-29      3 Finished John         1.48  
2 File_2020-09-29      4 Started  Mike        -0.0407
```

```
Changes_3_4 <- Docs_4 %>% dplyr::anti_join(Docs_3, by = c("Doc_ID", "Status", "Author"))
```

resulting in:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Filename        Doc_ID Status  Author Other_column
  <chr>            <int> <chr>   <chr>         <dbl>
1 File_2020-09-30      2 Waiting Mike         -0.267
2 File_2020-09-30      5 Started Betty        -1.36
```

Finally, I bind all changes together to get a log of all changes in a single tibble:

```
Changelog <- dplyr::bind_rows(Changes_1_2, Changes_2_3, Changes_3_4)
```

resulting in:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Filename        Doc_ID Status   Author Other_column
  <chr>            <int> <chr>    <chr>         <dbl>
1 File_2020-09-28      2 Started  Mike         0.807 
2 File_2020-09-28      3 Started  John         0.336 
3 File_2020-09-29      3 Finished John         1.48  
4 File_2020-09-29      4 Started  Mike        -0.0407
5 File_2020-09-30      2 Waiting  Mike        -0.267 
6 File_2020-09-30      5 Started  Betty       -1.36
```

For every `Doc_ID` I can then analyze the changes of their metadata over time in the Changelog.

Given the sheer number of files and entries, I need a more elegant solution to create the Changelog. How can I implement this procedure using iterations, preferably with the `purrr::map()` function of the `tidyverse`? My problem is that every iteration targets two consecutive indexed objects, and I found no example of this anywhere. I’m thinking of something like this (obviously this code doesn’t work, just inventing my own notaton for illustration):

```
Changelog <- df %>% split(.$Date) %>% 
  purrr::map_dfr(df_index+1 %>% dplyr::anti_join(df_index, by = c("Doc_ID", "Status", "Author")))
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? Maybe I should also change the initial loading of the csv-files into a list, instead of loading them into a single tibble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we can group/nest, lag, and compare:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # unnest
set.seed(42) # and then your `df <- tibble(...)`

df %>%
  nest_by(Filename) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(lastdata = lag(data)) %>%
  filter(lengths(lastdata) > 0) %>%
  mutate(
    diffs = purrr::map2(data, lastdata, ~ anti_join(.x, .y, by = c("Doc_ID", "Status", "Author")))
  ) %>%
  select(-data, -lastdata) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(diffs)
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#   Filename        Doc_ID Status   Author Other_column
#   <chr>            <int> <chr>    <chr>         <dbl>
# 1 File_2020-09-28      2 Started  Mike         0.633 
# 2 File_2020-09-28      3 Started  John         0.404 
# 3 File_2020-09-29      3 Finished John        -0.0947
# 4 File_2020-09-29      4 Started  Mike         2.02  
# 5 File_2020-09-30      2 Waiting  Mike         1.30  
# 6 File_2020-09-30      5 Started  Betty       -0.279
```

The important steps to look at are:

1. Initial grouped/nested setup:

   ```r
   df %>%
     nest_by(Filename) %>%
     ungroup() %>%
     mutate(lastdata = lag(data))
   # # A tibble: 4 x 3
   #   Filename                      data           lastdata
   #   <chr>           <list<tbl_df[,4]>> <list<tbl_df[,4]>>
   # 1 File_2020-09-27            [2 x 4]                [0]
   # 2 File_2020-09-28            [3 x 4]            [2 x 4]
   # 3 File_2020-09-29            [4 x 4]            [3 x 4]
   # 4 File_2020-09-30            [5 x 4]            [4 x 4]
   ```

   where the `data` column effectively contains your `Docs_1` through `Docs_2`, and `lastdata` contains the *previous* of `data`. This means that for the second row, `data` contains rows from `09-28` and `lastdata` contains rows from `09-27`.
2. Since we can't compare `09-27` to a previous day (and its `lastdata` is empty), we filter it out:

   ```r
     filter(lengths(lastdata) > 0)
   ```
3. Finally, we iterate down the columns, `anti_join`ing each pair of `lastdata` and `data`:

   ```r
     mutate(
       diffs = purrr::map2(data, lastdata, ~ anti_join(.x, .y, by = c("Doc_ID", "Status", "Author")))
     )
   # # A tibble: 3 x 4
   #   Filename                      data           lastdata diffs           
   #   <chr>           <list<tbl_df[,4]>> <list<tbl_df[,4]>> <list>          
   # 1 File_2020-09-28            [3 x 4]            [2 x 4] <tibble [2 x 4]>
   # 2 File_2020-09-29            [4 x 4]            [3 x 4] <tibble [2 x 4]>
   # 3 File_2020-09-30            [5 x 4]            [4 x 4] <tibble [2 x 4]>
   ```
4. Clean up by removing and unnesting.

Comment: You nailed it, thank you! Just out of curiosity: could the problem also be solved using the new rowwise() and summarise() functions of dplyr 1.0.0? Apparently they can replace purrr::map() functions in some use cases.

Comment: I don't think `rowwise` is what you want, since the data you're looking to include spans multiple rows. (And `rowwise` is not new, it's been around a while. Are you thinking `across`? It's new in dplyr-1.0.0.)

Comment: You're right. I had just thought about this comment from Hadley: "In combination with rowwise(), summarise() is now sufficiently powerful to replace many workflows that previously required a map() or apply() function.": https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/dplyr-1-0-0-summarise/#non-summaries

Comment: Btw: is the way I read in the files (see above) the best way? I load them into a separate tibble and then nest_by that tibble again. Should I be loading the files using a different map()-function than map_dfr to simplify subsequent processing?

Comment: I think it's fine. There are a few different ways, and without a lot more thought I have no reason to suggest an alternative at the moment. It certainly doesn't seem to be completely wrong.